# returning JSON list from Flask the secure way?

Tags: json, security, flask

I understand that using jsonify() on a list in Python Flask is insecure and therefore disabled. But what I don't understand is what I should do instead...

I have a list with groceries that I want to handle with jQuery, and would therefore want to return it to the user in some way. What is the *right* way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this means is that you can't have a list as a *top level* element for `jsonify()`. 
Basically:

```
jsonify({"data": [1, 2, 3]})
```

will work because the *outermost* (or top level) object is a `dict` (which gets converted into a JSON object). But this:

```
jsonify([1, 2, 3])
```

won't, because the *outermost* object is a `list` (which would normally get converted into a JSON array).

See the docs: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/security/#json-security

Comment: what exactly is *toplevel*?

Comment: Ok, so in some way it's just the array type that is a problem, thanks! :D